# Extra is always returning null in registerreceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

In my Android app I would like to be able to notify an activity when I receive an SMS, and give this activity the number of the sender. To achieve this goal I'm using a BroadcastReceiver class that collects the phone number(s) of SMS senders and send them in a broadcasted intent.

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final public static String SMS_BROADCAST = "myapp.BROADCAST_SMS";
    final public static String SMS_BROADCAST_EXTRA = "myapp.GET_SMS";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras == null)
            return;
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage Sms[] = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        String numbers[] = new String[pdus.length];
        //get the sms's
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            Sms[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            String sender = Sms[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            numbers[i] = sender;
        }
        //pass the number array to my activity via an intent.
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(SMS_BROADCAST);
        intent2.putExtra(SMS_BROADCAST_EXTRA, numbers);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent2);
    }
}
```

And here is where I register the receiver in my activity. I receive the intent, but the array of strings "numbers" is always null. If I try to do something with it, I always have a null pointer exception.

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SMSReceiver.SMS_BROADCAST);
        BroadcastReceiver SmsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals(SMSReceiver.SMS_BROADCAST)) {
                    String numbers[] = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(SMSReceiver.SMS_BROADCAST_EXTRA);
                    if (numbers == null) {
                        // This always appears in the log !!!
                        Log.d("NUMBERS", "IS NULL");
                        return;
                    }
                    // do something with the numbers
                }
            }
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(SmsReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
```

I still can't see what I did wrong, but I'm quite a newbie in Android development. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `getIntent()` != `intent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Activity` intent with method `getIntent()` instead `onReceive` intent

change to `getIntent()` to `intent`

```
String numbers[] = intent.getStringArrayExtra(SMSReceiver.SMS_BROADCAST_EXTRA);
```